# Application should not come to foreground when Activity starts in background

Tags: android

I have two activities in application one is login activity and other one is Menu activity, after clicking on login activity calls a service call to server in AsyncTask, here progress dialog spins.... minimize application. Now app moves to background.

After Service call is done, onPost method starting menu activity. code here is for staring menu activity is

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

But now application comes to foreground and shows Menu activity.

I don't want application to come to Foreground when activity started in background. Can any one have any idea where am doing wrong, please suggest me..

Manifest file code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.infinisource.iSolved_hcm_mobile"
          android:versionCode="9"
    android:versionName="7.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17"/>
    <!-- Internet Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- Network State Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <!-- Wifi State Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <!-- Access location permissions-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <permission
            android:name="com.infinisource.iSolved.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.infinisource.iSolved.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />


    <application
            android:name=".AppData"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:largeHeap="true"
            android:theme="@style/iSolvedTheme"
            android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MenuActivity"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: There is no concept of "activity starts in background" in Android. If you are starting an activity, it will come to the foreground. If you do not want the activity to come to the foreground, do not start the activity.

Comment: Thanks for information, it helped me.

I override following to methods to stop start activity when in background in BaseActivity

  void startActivity(Intent intent) {
        if(AppData.isApplicationForeground){
            super.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void finish() {
        if(AppData.isApplicationForeground){
            super.finish();
        }
    }